# Satin vs flat acrylic on old siding in the Pacific Northwest

Tags: painting, exterior

I have been investigating what types of exterior paint to use and have understood the following:

- Flat does a better job of hiding blemishes in the underlying siding or wood
- Satin has better moisture resistance and allows washing

The home is in a highlands area with precipitation approaching fifty inches annually. Moisture *is* a consideration.  But the siding is very old and rough.  So how can we go about choosing between them?

Note: I also have a follow-up/related question on [reducing the visibility of the imperfections when using Satin](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/249705/how-to-reduce-the-visibility-of-imperfections-in-the-underlying-siding-and-wood)

Comment: You'v got to decide which one is more important... opinion based.

Comment: Ay algae or mold should be cleaned off first.  The rough surface of the siding will make more difference than the type of paint.

Comment: _How_ to go about choosing is a short way of saying "what are the pros/cons". Vote to leave open. We can list factors (beyond what the OP has listed) that will help him decide.

Comment: I would say gloss has good weather and stain resistance and allows cleaning.  Satin is 1/3 of the way from flat to gloss.  Neither one will deal with degraded substrate, that's primer's job and your best answers won't involve water base anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received input from local contractors here : there is another formulation "low sheen" that straddles flat and satin and is manufactured in Portland.  I will be leaning towards this one.